# Unable to inject ngDialog into the controller properly

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and trying to open a dialog box using ngDialog.

This is my controller :

```
( function() {
        var myController = function($scope, myService, ngDialog) {
            $scope.title = "Getting data from service";
            $scope.openReportDialog = function() {
                alert("inside function");
                ngDialog.open({ template: '<h1>Pranjal</h1>' });
            };
            myService.getPlan().success(function(r,s,x){
                $scope.planData = r.plan;
            });
            myService.getPlan().success(function(r,s,x){
                $scope.userData = r.plan;
            });
        };
        angular.module("app").controller("myController", myController);
    }());
```

This is my view file :

```
<div class="container">

    <button ng-click="openReportDialog()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
    </button>

</div>
```

Everytime I am getting this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < dialog.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < v_sample.html:1

    Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=ngDialogProvider%20%3C-%20ngDialog%20%3C-%20myController
    at Error (native)
        at http://127.0.0.1:8020/OMS_Phase_3/lib/angular.min.js:6:416
        at http://127.0.0.1:8020/OMS_Phase_3/lib/angular.min.js:40:307
        at Object.d [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:8020/OMS_Phase_3/lib/angular.min.js:38:308)
        at http://127.0.0.1:8020/OMS_Phase_3/lib/angular.min.js:40:381
        at d (http://127.0.0.1:8020/OMS_Phase_3/lib/angular.min.js:38:308)
        at e (http://127.0.0.1:8020/OMS_Phase_3/lib/angular.min.js:39:64)
        at Object.g.instantiate (http://127.0.0.1:8020/OMS_Phase_3/lib/angular.min.js:39:213)
        at b.$get (http://127.0.0.1:8020/OMS_Phase_3/lib/angular.min.js:80:257)
        at $route.link (http://127.0.0.1:8020/OMS_Phase_3/lib/angular-route.js:977:26) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: have you injected `ngDialog` module in your app like `angular.module("app", ["ngDialog"])`

Comment: yes.. like this

( function() {
        angular.module("app", ["appRoute", "ngDialog"]);
}());

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that the application is unable to get the required dependencies. As you said in your comment, you are already adding "ngDialog" in your module definition. Can you please confirm if you are including `ngDialog.min.js` library while loading your application (may be in index.html) and it is getting accessed properly?

Comment: thanks. it's working now. i didn't included the file